# How do I say MAX date on join table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group

I am getting duplicate records on the join and I only want the MAX(most current) date on the NSANOTES.NOTEDATE.  How do you do that please?

```
SELECT NSAACTIVITY.NSAID ,
NSAACTIVITY.NSASERVICEIMPACTED "Type",  
NSAACTIVITY.NSAAPPROVED,
NSAACTIVITY.NSADESCRIPTION,
NSANOTES.NSANOTE 
FROM NSAUSER.NSAACTIVITY INNER JOIN NSAUSER.NSANOTES ON NSAACTIVITY.NSAID=NSANOTES.NSAID
WHERE TO_CHAR(NSAACTIVITY.NSASTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') BETWEEN '2013-06-28 10:59:59' AND '2013-07-01 06:00:01'
```

Comment: NSANOTES.NOTEDATE doesn't seem to be used in your query.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate records? Is it the entire record that's duplicated - `NASID`, `Type`, `NSAAPPROVED`, `NSADESCRIPTION`, `NSANOTE`? If so you can use a `SELECT DISTINCT`. If not the answer will vary.

Comment: Also note that your `WHERE` clause will perform a lot faster if you avoid calling `TO_CHAR` on the `NSASTART`. If you have an index on `NSASTART` you can optimize with it if you change your `WHERE` to `WHERE NSAACTIVITY.NSASTART BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2013-06-28 10:59:59' AND TIMESTAMP '2013-07-01 06:00:01'. With the `TO_CHAR` the best you can hope for is an index scan and you might not even get that.

Comment: Right, but I want the most current NSANOTES.NSANOTES to appear.  I am getting multiple records because of the join. How do I stop that and still get the most recent note field from the NSANOTES?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something on lines of below. I took the clue about using timestamp instead of to_char on your WHERE clause. Rest is merely a use of RANK() function. Hope this helps

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT act.NSAID,
               act.NSASERVICEIMPACTED "Type",
               act.NSAAPPROVED,
               act.NSADESCRIPTION,
               notes.NSANOTE,
               rank()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY act.NSAID ORDER BY notes.NOTEDATE DESC) rn
          FROM    NSAUSER.NSAACTIVITY act
               INNER JOIN
                  NSAUSER.NSANOTES notes
               ON act.NSAID = notes.NSAID
         WHERE act.NSASTART BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2013-06-28 10:59:59' AND TIMESTAMP '2013-07-01 06:00:01'
                                                            )
                                                            where rn=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using group by ?
something like:

```
SELECT NSAACTIVITY.NSAID ,
NSAACTIVITY.NSASERVICEIMPACTED "Type",  
NSAACTIVITY.NSAAPPROVED,
NSAACTIVITY.NSADESCRIPTION,
NSANOTES.NSANOTE,
MAX(NSANOTES.NOTEDATE)
FROM NSAUSER.NSAACTIVITY INNER JOIN NSAUSER.NSANOTES ON NSAACTIVITY.NSAID=NSANOTES.NSAID
WHERE TO_CHAR(NSAACTIVITY.NSASTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') BETWEEN '2013-06-28 10:59:59' AND '2013-07-01 06:00:01'
GROUP BY NSAACTIVITY.NSAID ,
NSAACTIVITY.NSASERVICEIMPACTED,  
NSAACTIVITY.NSAAPPROVED,
NSAACTIVITY.NSADESCRIPTION,
NSANOTES.NSANOTE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would do the trick (use a subquery)

```
SELECT NSAACTIVITY.NSAID ,
NSAACTIVITY.NSASERVICEIMPACTED "Type",  
NSAACTIVITY.NSAAPPROVED,
NSAACTIVITY.NSADESCRIPTION,
ns.NSANOTE 
FROM NSAUSER.NSAACTIVITY INNER JOIN NSAUSER.NSANOTES ns ON NSAACTIVITY.NSAID=ns.NSAID
WHERE TO_CHAR(NSAACTIVITY.NSASTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') BETWEEN '2013-06-28  10:59:59' AND '2013-07-01 06:00:01'
and ns.NOTESDATE= (SELECT MAX(ns2.NOTESDATE) FROM NSAUSER.NSANOTES ns2 where ns2.NSAID = ns.NSAID)
```

Comment: You would still get duplicate if you had two records for the same `NSANOTES.NSAID` with the same `NSANOTES.NOTESDATE` value. But based on what you had given us this is what I could come up with

Comment: What does the ns do in this line? FROM NSAUSER.NSAACTIVITY INNER JOIN NSAUSER.NSANOTES ns ON NSAACTIVITY.NSAID=NSANOTES.NSAID

Comment: its an alias that you can use in your query to refer to NSAUSER.NSANOTES